# How to select a button in array of items and unselect the previous value

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on grabbing an array of data from firestore. Only one item in this array of items can have the value "default" == true. The rest of the items will be false. I want to give the user the option of selecting one of the buttons and then removing the default value from the button that had the value of true. I know I can make a function to change the value in firestore with a listener function. I'd rather handle this locally so I save myself a read/write in firestore.

Do i need to map through the array and change state? any help is greatly appreciated.

My renderItem fucntion is

```
 if (item.type == 'car'){
                        return (
                          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.selectItem(item)} underlayColor={'transparent'}>
                            <LinearGradient key={key} style={{justifyContent: 'center', borderRadius: 30, width: 180, height: 120, alignSelf: 'center'}} colors={['#ff00ff', '#0066ff']}>

                                        <Text style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', marginRight: 5}}> 
                                        {checkMark}
                                        </Text>
                      <View style={{alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', width: 40, height: 40, borderRadius: 60/2, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                                    <Text style={{alignSelf:'center'}}>
                                    {car} 
                                    </Text>
                                </View>
                                <Text style={{marginTop: 5, fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 5, color: 'white', fontSize: 12, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',}}>
                                  {item.make} {item.model} {item.year}
                                </Text>
                                <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white', fontSize: 12, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',}}>
                                 {item.licensePlate} 
                                </Text>
                            </LinearGradient>
                          </TouchableHighlight>
                          )
                      }
                      if (item.type == 'bicycle') {
                        return (
                            <LinearGradient key={key} style={{justifyContent: 'center', borderRadius: 30, width: 180, height: 120, alignSelf: 'center'}} colors={['#99cc00', '#000099']}>
                                  <View style={{alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', width: 40, height: 40, borderRadius: 60/2, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                                        <Text style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}>
                                        {bicycle} 
                                        </Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <Text style={{marginTop: 5, fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 5, color: 'white', fontSize: 12, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',}}>
                                      {item.make} {item.model} {item.year}
                                    </Text>
                                    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white', fontSize: 12, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',}}>
                                     {item.licensePlate} 
                                    </Text>
                            </LinearGradient>

                          )
                        }
```

What I want to do is apply the check mark icon only when the user clicks on the button. Then it automatically deselects the other button. I've tried to filter out the array and change the value from there but I'm having a hard time filtering the specific index rather than getting all the values changed.

Comment: Hey, please show what you have tried so far to describe your use case more precise. Your question is more than unclear. On the other hand use Array.prototype.filter.

Comment: Hello and welcome @Kieran to the site. As is currently written we can not determine the best answer for your question due to lack of clarity on it. Please update your answer to a specific matter and add whatever you've tried so far.

Comment: i've updated the code. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Just filter your Array.

```js
var someArrayFromFirebase = [{"default": false}, {"default": true},{"default": false},{"default": false}];

var removeDefaultTrue = function() {
  someArrayFromFirebase = someArrayFromFirebase.filter(v => !v.default);
  render();
}

var render = function() {
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(someArrayFromFirebase);
}

render();
```

```html
<button onclick="removeDefaultTrue()" >Remove or whatever</button>

<div id="content"></div>
```

The render function is just for visualizing. The other function does the filtering. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by doing the following.

```
  var currentDefault = this.state.vehicleList.find(function(element, index) {
  return element.default == true;
  });
  var currentVehicle = this.state.vehicleList.indexOf(currentDefault);
  var selectedItem = this.state.vehicleList.indexOf(val);

   if (currentVehicle == selectedItem){
    console.log('same vehicle');
   } else {
    this.state.vehicleList[currentVehicle].default = false;
    this.state.vehicleList[selectedItem].default = true;
   }
```